# php multiple file upload oddity

Tags: php, forms, upload

[SOLVED] dont ask me how i have no idea, i didnt change anything but the names of the 2 form file inputs from uploadedfile and fuploadedfile to abc and abc2 and now it works, im as confused as you.

ok, i have 2 file inputs one called 'uploadedfile' the other called 'fuploadedfile'
i have a function i call to upload a file, which if tested on a single file works

```
uploadfile($_FILES["uploadedfile"]);
```

works

```
uploadfile($_FILES["fuploadedfile"]);
```

does not

i have tacked this to the end of the upload script to see what happens

```
echo var_dump($_FILES["uploadedfile"]);
echo var_dump($_FILES["fuploadedfile"]);
```

EDIT: this is what i get from each
uploadedfile:

```
array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "cat.gif" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/gif" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php59F9.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(14328) }
```

and this is what i get from fuploadedfile:

```
NULL
```

the first one prints out an array full of information relative to the uploaded file, which is good.
the second one gives me some "Undefined index" error, im uploading the same file via the same script, the only thing thats different is that ive called the second one a different name
which shouldnt effect the upload script because it uses a dynamic variable.

here's the upload script - http://pastebin.com/vkcZEmXp

Why is it doing this?

EDIT: this is pretty much the HTML form (sans the other random inputs), but i don't think it's the problem because the upload has worked for the first one.

```
<form name="mainform" id="mainform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />
<input name="fuploadedfile" type="file" />
<input class="formbtn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Debug it. No one is interested in debugging your code except of yourself.

Comment: @zerkms: your joking right? im asking because ive tried and cant work it out. 
@Damien: edited main post.

Comment: @Brae: omg, `var_dump($var)` right before undefined variable and see if there is any data. Have you looked at `var_dump($_FILES);`?? What line that error happened?

Comment: what is results when you put fuploadedfile above uploadedfile tag?

Comment: @zerkms: the error is coming FROM the var_dump(), how do you suggest i try debug further?

Comment: @Brae: `var_dump($_FILES);` and see if there is a file... don't be so silly

Comment: @simer + @zerkms: edited main post

Comment: @Brae: 3rd and last time: `var_dump($_FILES);`

Comment: @zerkms: it outputs the same as uploaded files, gives me an array full of info about the file, fuploadedfile still returns NULL

Comment: @Brae: can you just put a result into the question? Result **as-is**

Comment: @Brae: 4th time: put in the question what `var_dump($_FILES);` outputs to you. Just execute it, copy and paste to question.

Comment: @zerkms: your not making any sense, i alreaddy answered that, it outputs the array of data look in the main post it shows you.

ill post it here as well for your convienience ::: var_dump($_FILES) OUTPUTS THIS -> array(1) { ["uploadedfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(7) "cat.gif" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/gif" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php2BCD.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(14328) } }

Comment: @Brae: as you can see - there is no `fuploadedfile`. That means that you **haven't passed it**. Continue investigate your issue with any tool, that can show you headers passed, firebug, for example.

Comment: @zerkms: the script does 2 passes, one for 'u*' and one for 'fu*' BOTH return the array for the $_FILE and both return NULL for fu*.

Comment: @Brae: try to change names to `a` and `b` accordingly

Comment: @Brae: http://pastebin.com/u4Fq6CVw -- this works just fine for me

Comment: @zerkms: $_FILES is empty until i hit submit on the form to pass the files to uploader.php, how will that show anything ::: i tried to change the names to A and B and now they both return with errors O.o

Comment: @Brae: i've given you **working** script. Can you just try it, without any modifications?

Comment: @zerkms: the form with the var_dump()? it returns nothing. why would it? the $_FILE wont be populated until the file gets passed onto the uploader.php via the submit button, so before that its empty.

Comment: @Brae: yes. So chose 2 files and press submit button. That is the only way to send files using browser.

Comment: @zerksms: i also tried another version where the code might acctualy output something, the one you gave had no ECHO, so i tryed it and got this -> array(0) {}

Comment: SOLVED, edited main, i have no idea what happend but now its working, both are reporting a successfull file upload. all i did was change the form names again and its working. so confused.

Comment: @zerkms: you helped debug so if you want points for this just post a a random answer and ill give it to you :P

Comment: @Brae: done. also add as the comment what the real issue was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know what the actuall issue was, but seems like my advices helped ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As a test; try using the HTML exactly as you have posted it in your question.
I suspect there's an error in a different part of your HTML form.

I've tried your uploader.php exactly as you wrote it, together with a HTML page consisting of only of your form. I cannot reproduce your problem -- both files upload correctly although on my server I need to give a fully qualified path for $uploaded_target